# What is the correct way for the anchor tag's target attribute?

Tags: html, anchor

I have been using something like so, `<a href="myURL.php" target="blank">Some text</a>`, for almost 3 years now and I want to make sure I am not doing something terribly illegal.

After looking up some info I started to notice everywhere stated it as `target="_blank"`. This started to bring some concern to me that I may need to go back through all of the websites I have worked on and make changes to include `_`.

When I run it through the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) it does not cause an error and does not even inform me of a warning pertaining it.

My question:

1. Is this against the guidlines to not use the, `_`, underscore?
2. If this is against the guidelines then why does it not cause an
   error and why does it work?

As a side note, I couldn't find much info on this but I at least found the [specs for links](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html).

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target

Comment: The spec for `target` attribute values is here: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#valid-browsing-context-name-or-keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly-speaking, what you're doing (not using the underscore) is incorrect.

If you opt to simply use `target="blank"` then your link will still open correctly but with a subtle difference: clicking on the link will reuse the window opened last time instead of opening a new one.

This is because the `target` attribute contains the name of the frame the link should open in.  If a frame with the name 'blank' (as you're declaring) doesn't exist then it will open a new window and designate it with that name.  So, whenever another link within your page that also contains target="blank" is clicked upon, it's the same window that was opened last time (assuming that it's still open) that will change.

Basically, there's no massive need for you to go back through your old websites changing everything you've done, but you should consider changing to `target="_blank"` going forward if what you intend is for it to open a new tab/window each time.

Comment: This was an excellent explanation! I was just a little confused but this really cleared it up for me!

Comment: Glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 7):

`_blank` means "Open a new, unnamed window"

`blank` means "Use a window/tab/frame named 'blank'"

If you click on a second link with `target="blank"` then it will open in the same window as the first `target="blank"` link.

Comment: Ahh that makes a lot more sense! So if I use just `blank` or whatever I want to use it will open in that **same** tab when ever `blank` is specified.

Answer (score 2):

The `target` attribute can either be the name of a frame (which can be anything), or one of three special names that start with `_`.

Answer (score 2):

`target="blank"` means open in window named "blank". If the window named "blank" already exists, it will open site in that window. May be a frame in document.

`target="_blank"` means open in new window.